# how to copy a ShapeRange.group as picture

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use CopyPicture on ShapeRange.group. But i'm getting error at line 3.

```
    1  Dim gfsfd As Shape
    2  Set gfsfd = Selection.ShapeRange.Group
    3  gfsfd.CopyPicture xlPrinter, xlBitmap 'getting error here as below
```

Run-time error '1004'
Application-defined or object-defined error

[image: Check this image...]

Comment: Something like this  may work well ~Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D4").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
Worksheets("Sheet1").Paste _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E6")~CopyPicture method as it applies to the Shape object.
Copies the selected object to the Clipboard as a picture.
expression.CopyPicture(Appearance, Format)
expression Required. An expression that returns one of the above objects.
XlPictureAppearance
XlCopyPictureFormat

Comment: Let me try removing Selection. and add Worksheets("Sheet1"). Btw i'm grouping a text box and a picture to create shape "gfsfd" as above.

Comment: Not working skkakkar.

Comment: When executing this statement `MsgBox TypeName(Selection)
` message box  tells me its "DrawingObjects"

Comment: I only wanted to help you with correct syntax.  Try experimenting to your situation.

Comment: Try for a single picture whether it works ~shSource.Pictures.Copy
shDest.Range("yr range").Paste~ I am unsure whether you conveyed thanks after getting some success or on my comments only.

Comment: Thanks for your comments skkakkar. checking your solution.

Comment: Regarding Textbox  one example :-If I type "1234" in TextBox1 of UserForm it would copy and paste that value to my sheet called "Surf Tally" in cell "C16" as: "1234" Controls on a UserForm don't retain their values when it's unloaded. We have to refill them in the UserForm_Initialize event procedure.
We may try using the TextBox's ControlSource property? Set it like this:

'Surf Tally'!C16 Since you are grouping textbox and image.

Comment: Sorry for making you misunderstand. The "Text Box" which i meant above is not the "TextBox" of user form. I'm doing Insert->Shapes->Text Box. I mean its a shape object

Comment: And i just want to insert a "Text Box" on a inserted "Picture or image" then select both use `CopyPicture` Method to copy as bitmap. I want the image to be in the clipboard. because I'm using another app to create .bmp file from clipboard.

Comment: You may find [VBA Fill a text box with a picture in a worksheet](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/568219-visual-basic-applications-fill-text-box-picture-worksheet.html) helpful for your project.

Comment: Thank You checking the given link.

Comment: skkakkar please check the  uploaded image.

Comment: I have seen your uploaded image and it seems it similar to [[The Grammy Bump Chart in Excel](http://chandoo.org/wp/2011/02/22/the-grammy-bump-chart-in-excel/) . Please check this reference, though honestly I am not able to fully grasp it.

Comment: Thank you checking the link

Comment: Cya tomorrow with more details skkakkar.

Comment: I have posted a possible solution as an Answer, which may meet your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After review of your requirement as per uploaded image, we can follow the following steps.
1. Embed a picture to your worksheet. If you do not want to disturb your present sheet, then add a hidden sheet. The code to embed image ensures that picture remains on Excel as an embedded image, if you move your image, it is not going to corrupt your excel file with a broken link.

```
Sub Embed_picture()
    ' Change picture path as per your requirement
    Set oPic = Application.ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\my_dir\child1.jpg", False, True, 1, 1, 1, 1)
    oPic.ScaleHeight 1, True
    oPic.ScaleWidth 1, True

    oPic.Top = Range("E10").Top
    oPic.Left = Range("E10").Left
End Sub
```

2. Insert a TextBox on the image, but before it ensure that image is selected. Suitable text be incorporated in your text message replacing "Hello! Good Morning". I have not formatted anything such as Fill.ForeColor etc. which can be done as per your liking. Here is the code for this stage.

   ```
   Sub TextBox_on_embedded_image()
       ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Select
       ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 207, 260.25, 132.75 _
       , 28.5).Select
       Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
       "Hello! Good Morning"
       Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 19).ParagraphFormat. _
       FirstLineIndent = 0
       With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 19).Font
           .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
           .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
           .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
           .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorDark1
           .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
           .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
           .Fill.Transparency = 0
           .Fill.Solid
           .Size = 11
           .Name = "+mn-lt"
      End With
      Range("K6").Select
   End Sub
   ```
3. Next stage is to copy a screen image of cells E10:H20 containing embedded image with Text Box on Sheet1 to the Clipboard, and then it pastes the bitmap to another location on Sheet2.

Code for this stage is :

```
Sub copy2clipboard()
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E10:H20").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Paste _
       Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E6")
End Sub
```

Results obtined are shown in the following screenshot.
[image: Results snapshot]

Comment: I'm processing images of different resolutions. I cannot use `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E10:H20").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap`. So I'm using  `Selection.Cut`  `ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (JPEG)"`. Now i execute  `Debug.Print Selection.Name` which gives "Picture 6". I want to know how to use "CopyPicture" method on "Picture 6".

Comment: I shall revert back to you in about half an hour. I have done it by using shapes index method. I am trying to locate the correct syntax.

Comment: Please try to use similar syntax , though it is for deletion of a picture.  `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
Dim shape As Excel.shape

'For Each shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
 '       shape.Delete
'Next
ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).Delete` Infact in your initial post you mentioned xlBitmap as such I concentrated my efforts to the proposed method.

Comment: Thank you very much skkakkar i have learnt many things from your coding style.

Comment: You are making me learn. You are a good teacher. I don't know how to teach like you. I straight away give answers and not make others think.

Comment: @J.felix I am curious to know whether you have succeeded finally. Was my final comment of any use to you. Thanks for accepting the answer.